# Trouble positioning elements. with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have been trying to learn HTMl and CSS for a while, I already know some of the basics, but for a long time I have been struggling with positioning items where I want them.

I have followed many tutorial, and if I follow it exactly hoy they do it everything works perfect, but when I start playing with things around to make it a bit more complex, things don't behave the way that I expect to.

Check at this image for example. I have rows with elements, the first one I was able to cover 50%  percent of the screen with each item and align them in the middle with a float, but when I change the width to 40% instead 50%, they loose the center alignment and what is even more strange to me is that they move down a few pixels and loose the separation with the item bellow. 
I don't understand why changing the width affects its vertical position.

With the elements of the second row, that im positioning them as absolute, I can't figure out how to center them in the middle of the screen.

Ande the forth row, the beige and green boxes, I don't understand why the text on the beige box is on the bottom of the box and part of it is out of the box, while the text in all the other rows aligned vertical to the center of the box automatically.

[image: Sample]

Here is my code:

```css
       body {
                margin: auto;
                max-width: 4000px;
                height: 5000px;
                font-family: "Lato";
            }
            #text-1{
                background-color: black;
                color: white;
                width: 50%;
                padding: 20px, 50px;
                float: left;
                text-align: center;
                text-justify: auto;
            }
            
            #text-1:hover{
                background-color: white;
                color: black;
            }
            
            #text-2 {
                background-color: lightgray;
                color: black;
                width: 50%;
                padding: 20px, 50px;
                float: left;
                text-align: center;
                text-justify: auto;
            }
            
            #text-2:hover {
                background-color: white;
                color: black;
            }
            
             #text-3{
                background-color: black;
                color: white;
                width: 500px;
                
                padding: 0px, 50px;
                position: absolute;
                left:200px;
                top: 100px;
                text-align: center;
                
            }
            
            #text-3:hover{
                background-color: white;
                color: black;
            }
            
            #text-4 {              
                background-color: lightgray;
                color: black;
                width: 500px;
                padding: 0px, 50px;
                position: absolute;
                left: 700px;
                top: 100px;
                text-align: center;
                
            }
            
            #text-4:hover {
                background-color: white;
                color: black;
            }
            
            #text-5 {              
                background-color: lightpink;
                color: black;
                width: 100%;
                padding: 0px, 50px;
                position: fixed;
                top: 200px;
                text-align: center;
                
            }
            
            #text-5:hover {
                background-color: white;
                color: black;
            }
        
            a:link{
                text-decoration: none;
                color: inherit;
            }
            
            a:visited{
                text-decoration: none;
                color: inherit;
                
            }
            
            .box-1 {
                background-color: beige;
                color: black;
                width: 500px;
                height: 100px;
                position: relative;
                left: 100px;
                top:300px;
                text-align: center;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 1px;
                padding-left: 20px;
                padding-right: 20px;
                z-index: 1;
            }
            
            .box-2 {
                background-color: lightgreen;
                color: black;
                width: 200px;
                height: 100px;
                position: relative;
                left: 300px;
                top: 250px;
                padding: 20px, 20px,20px, 20px;
                text-align: center;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 1px;
                z-index: 0;
            }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet'>

        
        
        
    </head>
    
   
    <body>
        <div id="text-1">
            <a href="index.html" target="_blank">
                <p>Experimenting with one paragraph</p>
                <p>This button is . positioned with a float, so it will stick eother to the lef or right of the screen</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        
        <div id="text-2">
            <a href="index.html" target="_blank">
                <p>Another chunck of text</p>
                <p>This button is . positioned with a float, so it will stick eother to the lef or right of the screen</p>
            </a>    
        </div>
    
        <div id="text-3">
            <a href="index.html" target="_blank">
                <p>Button 3</p>
                <p>This button has an absolute posittion, so it doesn't float around.</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        
        <div id="text-4">
            <a href="index.html" target="_blank">
                <p>Button 4</p>
                <p>This button has an absolute posittion, so it doesn't float around.</p>
            </a>    
        </div>
        
        <div id="text-5">
            <a href="index.html" target="_blank">
                <p>Button 4</p>
                <p>This button has a fixed posittion, so it wont move when scrolling up or down</p>
            </a>    
        </div>
    
        <div class="box-1">
                <p>This box is poitioned in front of others by using a z-index higher than the box bellow.</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="box-2"></div>
                      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using Bootstrap. This will reduce your CSS code upto great extend. Bootstrap has a class called d-flex which means the content within the container marked with flex will be arranged as a horizontal grid automatically.

Comment: Thanks, I know that bootstrap makes it much easier, that's my. next course, but before I move on I really want to know the basics and understand why this is happening.

Comment: Just peeking at your code, most of those issue happening with the properties `width, padding, margin, position, left, top` so go through one by one that will give you an hint to fix it. I suggest you to remove everything and try fixing by adding individual `div` understand the properties of what they do.

Comment: I know you are just learning, but I would highly recommend skipping `float` elements and learn how to use the `flexbox` or `grid` models instead. CSS tricks has a really good tutorial on flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ As it stands right now, your question is too broad for Stack Overflow. You really need to limit your question to one issue. That said, good on you for not wanting to jump right into Bootstrap and understand the foundations first!

Comment: Thanks guys, I will take your advices in account!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want like this?

```css
body {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 4000px;
    height: 5000px;
    font-family: "Lato";
}
#text-1{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px, 50px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    text-justify: auto;
    position: relative;
}

#text-1:hover{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

#text-2 {
    background-color: lightgray;
    color: black;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px, 50px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    text-justify: auto;
    position: relative;
}

#text-2:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

 #text-3{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 0px, 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left:10%;
    top: 110px;
    text-align: center;

}

#text-3:hover{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

#text-4 {              
    background-color: lightgray;
    color: black;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 0px, 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 110px;
    text-align: center;

}

#text-4:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

#text-5 {              
    background-color: lightpink;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px, 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 200px;
    text-align: center;

}

#text-5:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

a:link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;

}

.box-1 {
    background-color: beige;
    color: black;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    top:300px;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 0;
}

.box-2 {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    color: black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
    top: 250px;
    padding: 20px, 20px,20px, 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.box-1 > p{
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="text-1">
        <a href="index.html" target="_blank">
            <p>Experimenting with one paragraph</p>
            <p>This button is . positioned with a float, so it will stick eother to the lef or right of the screen</p>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="text-2">
        <a href="index.html" target="_blank">
            <p>Another chunck of text</p>
            <p>This button is . positioned with a float, so it will stick eother to the lef or right of the screen</p>
        </a>    
    </div>

    <div id="text-3">
        <a href="index.html" target="_blank">
            <p>Button 3</p>
            <p>This button has an absolute posittion, so it doesn't float around.</p>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="text-4">
        <a href="index.html" target="_blank">
            <p>Button 4</p>
            <p>This button has an absolute posittion, so it doesn't float around.</p>
        </a>    
    </div>

    <div id="text-5">
        <a href="index.html" target="_blank">
            <p>Button 4</p>
            <p>This button has a fixed posittion, so it wont move when scrolling up or down</p>
        </a>    
    </div>

    <div class="box-1">
        <p>This box is poitioned in front of others by using a z-index higher than the box bellow.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-2"></div>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

In the 2nd row divs are aligned at the center by specifying width of #text-4 and #text-5 to 40% , left of #text-4 to 10% and left of #text-5 to 50%.
P tag inside #box-1 is aligned inside #box-1 by setting it's position absolute